# Opening a WebDav folder in Windows explorer fails on subsequent tries

Tags: webdav, ithit-webdav-server

I have a WebDav server built using the ITHit WebDav.Net classes.

I run the project in VS 2010 using IIS 7 (not the built-in dev web server) in release mode.

When the project starts up it launches IE and it displays a page that contains a button 'Browse using Windows Explorer'. The JavaScript code uses this span:

```
<span id="oViewFolder" style="behavior:url(#default#httpFolder)"></span>
```

to open Windows Explorer by calling oViewFolder.navigate(webDavFolderUrl), where webDavFolderUrl is:

```
http://localhost:80/WebDavApp/
```

I already mapped the webdav folder using the Windows Explorer Map Network Drive -> Connect to a Web site that you can use ... and so on.

The problem that I experience is that the button works fine at the beginning, it launches a Windows Explorer window, however, if I leave that IE page and go to another app, when I move back to the IE page the button stops working, i.e. it doesn't open Windows Explorer anymore (I closed it before), and it displays a custom error message (the message is not useful because the navigate function returns FAILED instead of OK). If I restart the WebDav server, it works again, but not always, sometimes I have to restart IIS for the button to work again. The WebDav server works though.

Has anyone experienced this behavior? Any resolution to get rid of it?

I am using Windows 7 64 bit, SP1 with all the updates up-to-date, and IE 9.

Answer (score 0):

I created a bug for this issue.

You may use the next work-around:

```
Type in Windows Explorer
\\localhost@80\davwwwroot\WebDavApp\
```

The '@port' segment is optional if default port 80 is used.

You may create shortcut if your server address doesn't change.

Comment: I noticed that destroying/creating dynamically the span that contains 'behavior:url(#default#httpFolder)' by manipulating the DOM seems to do the trick